# Lacking OpenCL support on macbook pro

Tags: gpu, mac

I've a macbook pro and I tried to mine, but there is a problem, I can mine only with CPU because I get the error

```
No OpenCL-compatible GPUs detected 
2013.04.11 [15:16]  Lacking OpenCL support. If you want to use GPUs, please install the latest drivers from your graphics card manufacturer. 
2013.04.11 [15:17]  Warning: Electricity-wasting slow CPU implementation in use
```

How can I use my GPU??

Comment: ... did you try installing the latest drivers from your graphics card manufacturer?

Comment: It would help if you provided full details of your hardware, both macbook pro model as well as the GPU inside it.

Comment: It's also worth noting, as always, that you will almost certainly be paying more electricity costs than you will earn in mining--not to mention the negative impact on your macbook pro of the added heat from running gpu and or cpu at full tilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started down the same path as you with my Macbook Pro early-2011 model, and got the same error. My model includes the Intel HD Graphics 3000, and there are no Intel-based OpenCL drivers for it. When I did enable a miner on the Core i7 CPU alone, I got 1.8Mh/s using the CPU, which is poor.

AFAICT, even if you have an OpenCL-compatible Intel GPU, (the Core i5 and i7 are OpenCL compatible on Windows, and Xeon and Xeon Phi on Linux) I've read nowhere that states it's even possible to "GPU mine" with it, either Linux/Windows/Mac... I may be wrong :)

If you have an earlier Macbook Pro, a model that includes an NVIDIA GPU, like the GeForce 650M or 9600M GT, you may have some luck getting OpenCL to work. You can try reading the [How to Run Bitcoin Miner on Mac OS X](http://josh.thisistaken.com/2011/05/how-to-run-bitcoin-miner-on-mac-os-x.html) guide, but even if it works you'll only get 3.8Mh/s (still not very good).

In short, unless you can get at least 300Mh/s, like from an AMD GPU, [it's probably not worth the cost in electricity](http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com/).